# [ROS2] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from the examples of ROS 2 I tried to copy the AddTwoInts Example to my own package.
ros2 run try_srv add_two_ints_server generates an error when importing AddTwoInts

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'try_srv'
```

thought the reason is that the idl file is not generated (can't find them in install or build folder).

Changing from try_srv.srv import AddTwoInts back to from example_interfaces.srv import AddTwoInts works fine

this is the folder structure

[image: image description]

this is the package file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format2.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>try_srv</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>migrated from examples</description>

  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>

  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>

  <exec_depend>rclpy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>

  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

is the folder and package.xml structure ok ?

if so what else could be the reason that the import fails ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318509/%5Bros2%5D-modulenotfounderror:-no-module-named/) by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2019-03-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-14**:
Can you please update your question with a link to the tutorial that you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 2, message generation is done using the CMake macro [rosidl_generate_interfaces](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/blob/416ebd84a678178f8e8941a1961af8abe7514251/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake), you can find an example of that macro invocation [here](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/8fa6936cf0a5fd743e1456a88b2c1450c173e7aa/sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt#L51).

As your package is a pure python package, it cannot invoke that CMake macro and generate the files.

---

Looking at your folder structure, the AddTwoInts_{Request,Reply}.msg files are not necessary. These will be generated automatically from your srv file.

---

In the package.xml:
If your srv file depend on `std_msgs`, the `std_msgs` dependency needs to be listed as a `build_depend` as well as an `exec_depend`.

---

Finally, it is recommended to have the message definitions in a separate package and then import them from the packages that have the actual code and use them. If you want to use messages/services from the same package, you will need to specify it in your CMakeLists.txt by using the macro `rosidl_target_interfaces`, an example can be found [here](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/8fa6936cf0a5fd743e1456a88b2c1450c173e7aa/sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt#L73)

HTH

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2019-03-14**:
thanks for the help will check it out

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2019-03-15**:
now I was able to create a try_srv and a try_srv_msgs package which both work as expected. Thanks a lot